VoIP push notifications with django to iOS
Currently, I am using fcm-django to send fcm notifications to both android and iOS and for iOS, i set header apns-push-type: voip. Is it enough for a notification to be treated as voip push notification. On client side, i am using react-native-voip-push-notification, but in the listeners, i am not receiving any notification object.
So, How to properly send a voip push from django and handle it on react native side.
